# All homomorphisms from the general linear group

Tags: group-theory

What are the all group homomorphisms from the general linear group $GL(n,R)$ to the special linear group $SL(n,R)$?  One kind of homomorphism arises when we send a matrix to the matrix divided by its determinant.  Are there yet other examples?

Comment: $X\mapsto X/\det X$ will not land you in ${\rm SL}(n,\Bbb R)$ unless $n=1$, because $\det((\det X)I_n)=(\det X)^n$. You will need to use the $n$th root of $\det X$ instead, which won't work if $n$ is even since $\det$ can be negative.

Comment: ok..my mistake .....but still what are homomorphism there?